# QGIS: Select by expression on the same layer with condition

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, select-by-expression

[image: Expression]

What I am trying to achieve is selecting the lines that have the value of the field "Heizlast in kW" = 0 + the lines that touch it (like the selection in the picture above).

Using the expression below I am able to select the first match of the line that meets the condition where the value is 0. Is there a way to iterate through all the matching arrays and pass them to the Select by Expression so that the second, third match and so on are being validated?

```
array_contains( 
    aggregate(
        layer:='HA',
        aggregate:='array_agg',
        expression:=$id,
        filter:=intersects(@geometry, geometry(get_feature('HA','Heizlast in kW',0)))   
),$id)
```

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to put your code attempt in the body of the Question on a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all the features where "Heizlast in kW" = 0 using a basic `if` expression.

You can select all the features intersecting a feature where "Heizlast in kW" = 0 using `overlay_intersects` eg:

```
overlay_intersects('HA',@feature,limit:=-1,filter:="Heizlast in kW"=0)
```

Combine these into one expression that returns an array, and checks if it has any features (`array_length` >=1):

```
array_length(
    if("Heizlast in kW"=0,array(@feature),
    overlay_intersects('Modified_geometry_0b8f3bdc_2883_4da5_bb77_d36da3c4074d',@feature,limit:=-1,filter:="Heizlast in kW"=0))
)>=1
```